# How to add External DLL Path for CMake

Tags: c++, c, windows, cmake

I need to include an external DLL in CMake so I can run the app.

How do I add either the DLL or the Path containing the DLL to CMake?

Path:  `C://Users//myuser//Desktop//MyLib.dll`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do in this case is copy the dll to the bin directory containing the application executable. Then when you run it, windows will automatically look and find the dll from the app's directory.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly encourage to use [CMake 'install' rule](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/install.html) which - as I understand - is dedicated for the purpose you would like to achieve.

The following snippet included to the end of **CMakeList.txt** file should do the job:

```
install(
   TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
   DESTINATION .
)

install(
   DIRECTORY ${dir_where_dll_is_stored}
   DESTINATION .
   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.dll"
)
```